# Android, how to add toolbar in my Preferences?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

First, I am using Jetpack Navigation Component - navigation drawer.

And "No Action Bar" is my app's main style.

```xml
    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PrefsTheme</item>
    </style>
```

Here is the manifest.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxx">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Because I use Jetpack Navigation Component, it is a single activity pattern.

In general, my UIs have a custom toolbar.
It's ok.

But in case of the Settings UI, I faced a problem...

I am using Jetpack Preferences. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settigs

My settings UI extends "PreferenceFragmentCompat" and it is defined in "nav_graph.xml", too.

So it can be accessed by below code:

```
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.settingsFragment)
```

Because my app uses "NoActionBar", the preference has no action bar too.
And the preference is made by Jetpack Preferences, I cannot add a custom toolbar.

Is there any good idea/solution, please?

Comment: Hello sir, Found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of solutions. Create another style the enables actionbar to true.

```
<style name="AppTheme.WithActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PrefsTheme</item>
</style>
```

Then apply that theme specifically in your desired activity only inside Manifest.

```
<activity
        android:name="YourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WithActionBar" />
```

Comment: My preference is in the same activity... According to your opinion, I should move my preference out to another nav graph. But it doesn't look like a solution that I want.

Comment: @yoonhok please add some of your your activity code and how you defined your activity in manifest to better understand the problem

Comment: I added my full manifest code. It has just single activity because I use Jetpack Navigation Component.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jetpack navigation drawer the `MainActivity` doesn't have `Actionbar`, also I have Preference with `Actionbar`, just i'm using `AppTheme`

```
<activity
        android:name="YourPreferenceActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

> Note: you can remove the theme in `PreferenceActivity` if your default
>   theme is `AppTheme`

MainActivity with No action bar theme

```
<activity
            android:name="com.jca.dastuurkajsl.ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

here is how my **AppTheme** looks like

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**AppTheme.NoActionBar**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Yes, I am using Jetpack navigation component with Navigation drawer. But my preference is in the nav_graph.

Comment: So I think you didn't use Activity to hold the fragment of the preference

Comment: I don't want separate activity for preference instead i want to use PreferenceFragmentCompat directly with toolbar. is it possible ?